Absolute Layout no aparece
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y al principio si se mostraba el Absolute layout. Pero despues sin darme cuenta se borro y no me aparece la opción para aplicarla en ningún frame o panel. Y no es problema de la librería porque si esta en libraries (ya intente borrarla y volverla a poner), incluso en el proyecto. Pero si creo otro proyecto no aparece la opción.

